# flexbox wrapping order and groups with bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, flexbox, bootstrap-4

Not necessarily a bootstrap question, although I am doing this with bootstrap 4... I'm building a top nav using bootstrap.  In the top nav I've got several components of which I want to control how they wrap as the screen gets narrower.

I'm struggling a bit because the wrapping behavior I want to achieve is by no means default and I'm not sure how to do it or if it's possible.

In a wide screen, I would see this:
[image]
A and B are left aligned, while C, D and E are right aligned.

As the screen narrows a bit, I would see this:
[image]

Narrowing further:
[image]

Narrowing more:
[image]

I'm just not sure how to get the wrapping order and justification.  I've tried grouping various components together with divs, and nothing seems to work right.

Comment: what are your attempts ? order and mediaquerie ?

Comment: Not sure what you want the final result to be. Do you want all die columns to stay next to eachother with equal widths?

Comment: Bootstrap4 has classes for ordering... 'order-1' 'order-sm-2' etc

Comment: Make a snippet or fiddle of what you have got so far, we can then edit it to show you.

Comment: Please post the code you've attempted.

Comment: @G-Cyr - I have not used order or mediaqueries.  I don't want to code for specific dimensions, I want to control wrapping behavior for across all screen widths because the content in each component could change, so wrapping may be different at different breakpoints based on the content

Comment: @Toast - the images show what I want the result to be.  It shows how I want the wrapping to behave based on content size of each component and the overall width of the screen

Answer (score 0):

Start mobile and use `offset-*` and `order-*` classes accordingly. You need to reset `offset-*` and `order-*` to `*-0` for each one of break points.

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-3 order-1 order-sm-1 order-md-1 order-lg-1 mb-3">
      <div class="w-100 bg-info p-3 d-flex justify-content-center"> A</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-1 order-3 order-sm-4 order-md-5 order-lg-2  mb-3 ">
      <div class="w-100 bg-info p-3 d-flex justify-content-center"> B</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-5 order-5 order-sm-5 order-md-2 order-lg-3 offset-7 offset-sm-6 offset-md-1 offset-lg-0 mb-3">
      <div class="w-100 bg-info p-3 d-flex justify-content-center"> C</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-2 order-4 order-sm-2 order-md-3 order-lg-4 offset-9 offset-sm-6 offset-md-0 mb-3">
      <div class="w-100 bg-info p-3 d-flex justify-content-center"> D</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-1 order-2 order-sm-3 order-md-4 order-lg-5 offset-8 offset-sm-0 mb-3">
      <div class="w-100 bg-info p-3 d-flex justify-content-center"> E</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

#### Each one of the break-points separately.

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<h1 class="text-center m-3">xs</h1>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-3 order-1 mb-3">
      <div class="w-100 bg-info p-3 d-flex justify-content-center"> A</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-1 order-3 mb-3 ">
      <div class="w-100 bg-info p-3 d-flex justify-content-center"> B</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-5 offset-7 order-5  mb-3">
      <div class="w-100 bg-info p-3 d-flex justify-content-center"> C</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-2 order-4 offset-9  mb-3">
      <div class="w-100 bg-info p-3 d-flex justify-content-center"> D</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-1 order-2 offset-8  mb-3">
      <div class="w-100 bg-info p-3 d-flex justify-content-center"> E</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<h1 class="text-center m-3">sm</h1>
<div class="container ">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3 order-sm-1 mb-3">
      <div class="w-100 bg-info p-3 d-flex justify-content-center"> A</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-1 order-sm-4  mb-3 ">
      <div class="w-100 bg-info p-3 d-flex justify-content-center"> B</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-5 order-sm-5 offset-sm-6 mb-3">
      <div class="w-100 bg-info p-3 d-flex justify-content-center"> C</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 order-sm-2  offset-sm-6 mb-3">
      <div class="w-100 bg-info p-3 d-flex justify-content-center"> D</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-1 order-sm-3">
      <div class="w-100 bg-info p-3 d-flex justify-content-center"> E</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<h1 class="text-center m-3">md</h1>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3 mb-3">
      <div class="w-100 bg-info p-3 d-flex justify-content-center"> A</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-1 order-5">
      <div class="w-100 bg-info p-3 d-flex justify-content-center"> B</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-5 offset-1 mr-auto">
      <div class="w-100 bg-info p-3 d-flex justify-content-center"> C</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-2 col-lg-2">
      <div class="w-100 bg-info p-3 d-flex justify-content-center"> D</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-1 col-lg-1">
      <div class="w-100 bg-info p-3 d-flex justify-content-center"> E</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<h1 class="text-center m-3">Lg</h1>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-3  col-lg-3">
      <div class="w-100 bg-info p-3 d-flex justify-content-center"> A</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-1 col-lg-1">
      <div class="w-100 bg-info p-3 d-flex justify-content-center"> B</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-5 col-lg-5">
      <div class="w-100 bg-info p-3 d-flex justify-content-center"> C</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-2 col-lg-2">
      <div class="w-100 bg-info p-3 d-flex justify-content-center"> D</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-1 col-lg-1">
      <div class="w-100 bg-info p-3 d-flex justify-content-center"> E</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Increase/decrease `col-*` and `offset-*` classes, if they are not the same as those in the img.

Check in full screen or visit these two links

1. https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rvorge
2. https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MGZBNw